# Unable to rotate copyright (&copy;) character

Tags: html, css

I can't rotate © character. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

```css
.copy {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Arial;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  text-orientation: mixed;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<span class="copy">&copy; This is not working.</span>
<span class="copy">&amp; This is working.</span>
```

Comment: It is working...

Comment: But it is rotating..

Comment: You just need to use `text-orientation: sideways;` instead of `mixed` .. your rotation is fine

Comment: You should then rotate it 270deg because I beleive it rotates clockwise. So it should be `transform: rotate(270deg)`

Comment: @SumeshTG For me it's rotating 180 degrees, unlike the rest of the text. https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvE8m.png

Comment: Please focus on &copy; character only, it is rotated in wrong direction unlike the rest of the text. :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use this :

`sideways`

Causes characters to be laid out as they would be horizontally, but with the whole line rotated 90° clockwise.

```css
.copy {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Arial;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  text-orientation: sideways-right;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<span class="copy">&copy; This is not working.</span>
<span class="copy">&amp; This is working.</span>
```

EDIT - You could use `sideways-right` since there aren't many browsers supporting `sideways` - they both work for me

EDIT 2 -

`sideways-right`

An alias to sideways that is kept for compatibility purposes.

But both actually seems supported by most major browsers

Comment: Note that for improved browser support, some browser will need the `-webkit-` prefix

Comment: meaning `-webkit-text-orientation: sideways; /* for Webkit */`

Comment: Yes, it is working! Could You explain why copyright character behaviour is different from other entities/special characters?

Answer (score 3):

You can rotate the text with only `transform`, it's supported in all major browsers even old IEs.

```css
.copy {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-100%, 100%);
  transform-origin: left bottom;
}
```

```html
<span class="copy">&copy; Hello World</span>
```

Comment: Gonna upvote this - since it has a better browser support status.